Example of using `linkOnly` from the async library
I found what I'd imagine to be a useful function in the illustrious async library that allows a thread to propagate an exception if and only if the exception passes a predicate - with a type of SomeException -> Bool.
This is the dilemma - SomeException doesn't implement Eq, so casting my particular exception type into SomeException would be fruitless. Likewise, I tried to use cast from Data.Typeable, but that didn't seem to work either.

cast from Data.Typeable will work, you just have to hold it right. For example:
isIOError :: SomeException -> Bool
isIOError (SomeException e) = isJust (cast e :: Maybe IOError)

Of course you can write more exciting predicates that actually do some computation with your custom exception instance -- this one is just to demonstrate the base plan.

Ohhhh okay, so you cast the existentially quantified type wrapped by SomeException, and not the SomeException itself - that makes a lot of sense! Thank you!

Though it would've been obvious had I looked at the documentation longer, the Exception typeclass provides a fromException :: SomeException -> Maybe a function, which solved this issue. I'm not sure why Data.Typeable didn't do the trick, but who's complaining.

cast only works if two types are actually the same. SomeException and your exception type are not the same type, so of course cast fails. SomeException contains a value that may be of your exception type though. fromException extracts that value and calls cast on it.

Not exactly the same issue, but related: https://discourse.haskell.org/t/to-fromexception-question-solved/10310
